# How to Disable page bounce in Flutter Tab?

Tags: flutter, swipe, tabview, bounce

i have a layout that if the index of `tabView` is 0, then show a widget in AppBar. i can do it. But, the problem is when you swipe the `tabView` fast, the page is bounce.

[image]

Can we disable the page bounce? or any other solution?
here is my code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  int _currentIndex;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    _currentIndex = 0;
    _tabController.animateTo(_currentIndex);
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex = _tabController.index;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page ${_currentIndex}'),
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: [
            Tab(text: 'One',),
            Tab(text: 'Two',),
            Tab(text: 'Three',),
          ],
        ),
        leading: _currentIndex == 0? Icon(Icons.ac_unit): Container(),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          Container(color: Colors.red,),
          Container(color: Colors.green,),
          Container(color: Colors.blue,),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TabBarView` has default physics `PageScrollPhysics`, you can change it to see which physics works best for you, `AlwaysScrollablePhysics` might do the trick

Comment: i have tried 
`///
/// AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics
/// BouncingScrollPhysics
/// ClampingScrollPhysics
/// FixedExtentScrollPhysics
/// NeverScrollableScrollPhysics
/// PageScrollPhysics
/// RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics
///`
but still not working